# Textos que precisam de tradução na tela de exclusão de post

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Quando vou sugerir a exclusão de um post na ferramenta de análise, ainda temos os textos sem tradução. Veja:

[image: traduzir]

E aí tem os comentários automáticos que são postados também. Alguns exemplos:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3290/101

> Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation, you will be able to vote up questions and answers that you found helpful.

e

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post

e

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.

e

> Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.